# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, undefined, typeerror

I am making a card game using React, and for some reason I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined`.

The Code causing the error:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Card from "./components/Card";

const App = () => {
    const [cards, setCards] = useState([
        {
            name: "King",
            img: "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/king-crown-esport-logo-design_177315-269.jpg",
            pts: 10000,
        },
        {
            name: "Minister",
            img: "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/51/59/b3/5159b321713edef6c6a3b8f930f667a1.jpg",
            pts: 5000,
        },
        {
            name: "Cop",
            img: "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/police-officer-badge-icon-vector-260nw-613493573.jpg",
            pts: 100,
        },
        {
            name: "Thief",
            img: "https://images1.livehindustan.com/uploadimage/library/2019/05/03/16_9/16_9_1/thief_symbolic_photo__1556892712.jpg",
            pts: 0,
        },
    ]);

    const [shuffledCards, setShuffledCards] = useState([]);

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        const randCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * (cards.length + 1))];
        setShuffledCards([...shuffledCards, randCard]);
        setCards(cards.filter((c) => c !== randCard));
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>\
            {shuffledCards.map((c) => (
                <Card img={c.img} name={c.name} pts={c.pts} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The link to the project (online Gitpod.io) - https://purple-salmon-uy3kza3n.ws-us10.gitpod.io/?folder=vscode-remote%3A%2F%2Fsapphire-quokka-1i5clgk7.ws-us09.gitpod.io%3A443%2Fworkspace (caution it might change, some weird gitpod thing)

Now, when I printed the `shuffledCards` array in the `for` loop, after some loops I noticed an undefined object was getting added to the array. I think that's the problem, and I don't know why or how it's happening, and also how to fix it.

Looking forward to hearing from you guys. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: When do you want the cards to be shuffled? Currently you are attempting to do it each time the component renders. It's a bit redundant to store 2 arrays in state, just store the one and shuffle it in a lifecycle hook.

Comment: @DrewReese Do u think that will fix the error?

Comment: @DrewReese I am new to React and JavaScirpt, can u tell how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue is how you compute a random card, you are indexing out of the array.

```
const randCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * (cards.length + 1))];
```

You want to use the length.

```
const randCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * (cards.length))];
```

Another issue is that you are unconditionally updating state from the body of the component, this will lead to render looping.

Place the loop in an `useEffect` hook and use a functional state update since you are enqueueing state updates in a loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    const randCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * (cards.length))];
    setShuffledCards((shuffledCards) => [...shuffledCards, randCard]);
    setCards((cards) => cards.filter((c) => c !== randCard));
  }
}, []);
```

It's redundant to store two arrays. I would look into and implement the [fisher-yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

Here's an example effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCards((cards) => {
    // create copy
    const shuffledCards = cards.slice();

    // shuffle
    for (let i = cards.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      [shuffledCards[i], shuffledCards[randIndex]] = [
        shuffledCards[randIndex],
        shuffledCards[i]
      ];
    }

    // return next state
    return shuffledCards;
  });
}, [shuffledCards]);
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-typeerror-cannot-read-property-img-of-undefined]

In this demo I added a button to shuffle, and this updates the `useEffect` dependency to trigger another shuffle. This effect dependency can be anything you need it to be triggered by though for your specific use-case.

demo code

```
const App = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([
    {
      name: "King",
      img:
        "https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/king-crown-esport-logo-design_177315-269.jpg",
      pts: 10000
    },
    {
      name: "Minister",
      img:
        "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/51/59/b3/5159b321713edef6c6a3b8f930f667a1.jpg",
      pts: 5000
    },
    {
      name: "Cop",
      img:
        "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/police-officer-badge-icon-vector-260nw-613493573.jpg",
      pts: 100
    },
    {
      name: "Thief",
      img:
        "https://images1.livehindustan.com/uploadimage/library/2019/05/03/16_9/16_9_1/thief_symbolic_photo__1556892712.jpg",
      pts: 0
    }
  ]);

  const [shuffledCards, setShuffledCards] = useState(true);
  const shuffle = () => setShuffledCards((t) => !t);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCards((cards) => {
      const shuffledCards = cards.slice();

      for (let i = cards.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        [shuffledCards[i], shuffledCards[randIndex]] = [
          shuffledCards[randIndex],
          shuffledCards[i]
        ];
      }
      return shuffledCards;
    });
  }, [shuffledCards]);

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
        {cards.map((c) => (
          <Card key={c.name} img={c.img} name={c.name} pts={c.pts} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <button type="button" onClick={shuffle}>
        Shuffle Cards
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Actually @Drew Reese, since `Math.floor` is being used the normal array length should work just fine. 
`const randCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * (cards.length)];
`

Comment: @DrewReese, I tried useEffect, still gave me the error, will try your initial suggestion

Comment: @SakisTsalk, are u sure?

Comment: Yes, check [Math.Random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: @DrewReese thank u much, it's working now